# Multiplication of JavaRDD object

Tags: java, matrix

Is it general possible to multiply two [JavaRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaRDDLike.html) objects like matrices in Java?
For example if I create a [DenseMatrix](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/DenseMatrix.html) I can use the method

```
multiply(y: DenseMatrix): DenseMatrix
```

I want to find similar easy implementation for two JavaRDD objects.